# Kafka Ranger SSL integration issue

Tags: apache-ranger

We are trying to enable SSL connection between Apache Ranger and Kafka cluster. After creating keystore and truststore for both Kafka and Ranger, we are unable to connect Kafka to Ranger and we are getting the following error message:

```
[2020-06-25 20:47:40,013] ERROR Unable to get the Credential Provider from the Configuration (org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.utils.RangerCredentialProvider)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value of property hadoop.security.credential.provider.path must not be null
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1134)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1115)
at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.utils.RangerCredentialProvider.getCredentialProviders(RangerCredentialProvider.java:68)
at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.utils.RangerCredentialProvider.getCredentialString(RangerCredentialProvider.java:46)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.getCredential(RangerRESTClient.java:386)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.getKeyManagers(RangerRESTClient.java:272)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.buildClient(RangerRESTClient.java:188)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.getClient(RangerRESTClient.java:176)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.getResource(RangerRESTClient.java:156)
at org.apache.ranger.admin.client.RangerAdminRESTClient.createWebResource(RangerAdminRESTClient.java:275)
at org.apache.ranger.admin.client.RangerAdminRESTClient.getServicePoliciesIfUpdated(RangerAdminRESTClient.java:126)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PolicyRefresher.loadPolicyfromPolicyAdmin(PolicyRefresher.java:264)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PolicyRefresher.loadPolicy(PolicyRefresher.java:202)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PolicyRefresher.run(PolicyRefresher.java:171)


[2020-06-25 20:47:40,013] ERROR PolicyRefresher(serviceName=KafkaTest): failed to refresh policies. Will continue to use last known version of policies (51) (org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PolicyRefresher)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TrustManager is not specified
at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.getSSLContext(RangerRESTClient.java:369)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.buildClient(RangerRESTClient.java:190)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.getClient(RangerRESTClient.java:176)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.RangerRESTClient.getResource(RangerRESTClient.java:156)
at org.apache.ranger.admin.client.RangerAdminRESTClient.createWebResource(RangerAdminRESTClient.java:275)
at org.apache.ranger.admin.client.RangerAdminRESTClient.getServicePoliciesIfUpdated(RangerAdminRESTClient.java:126)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PolicyRefresher.loadPolicyfromPolicyAdmin(PolicyRefresher.java:264)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PolicyRefresher.loadPolicy(PolicyRefresher.java:202)
at org.apache.ranger.plugin.util.PolicyRefresher.run(PolicyRefresher.java:171)
```

In Kafka-Ranger plugin, I have configured below properties in install.properites

```
COMPONENT_INSTALL_DIR_NAME=/home/ec2-user/kafka
POLICY_MGR_URL=https://public-dns-of-ec2:6182 
REPOSITORY_NAME=KafkaTest 
SSL_KEYSTORE_FILE_PATH=/etc/hadoop/conf/<keystore>.jks
SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=<password >
SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILE_PATH=/etc/hadoop/conf/<truststore>.jks 
SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=<password>
```

**Note: We are not using Ambari**

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Kafka-Ranger-SSL-integration-issue/td-p/298747

Answer (score 1):

Make sure following properties are set:-

```
xasecure.policymgr.clientssl.keystore.credential.file=jceks://file/{{credential_file}}
xasecure.policymgr.clientssl.truststore.credential.file=jceks://file/{{credential_file}}
xasecure.policymgr.clientssl.truststore=/path/to/truststore
```